# Draw disjoint pie C#

Tags: c#, drawing

I would like to 60 pie slices with of 5 degree and each with 1 degree of separation. However, with the code below, the outcome looks like the image below with a big black centre, is there anyway that I can modify the code to avoid that?

[image: Output]

```
    Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

    // Create pen.
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

    // Create rectangle for ellipse.
    //RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(150.0F, 10.0F, 200F, 300.0F);

    // Create start and sweep angles.
    float startAngle = 270F;
    float sweepAngle = 4F;


    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++ )
    {
        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(50F, 10.0F, 200F, 200F);
        startAngle = startAngle + 6F;
        g.DrawPie(blackPen, rect, startAngle, sweepAngle);
        //start = start + 1f;
    }
```

Regards

Comment: What would you have it do instead? There are only so many pixels available, and most of them get drawn as black by at least one individual slice being drawn.

Comment: Its normal that center is black. Try to draw with a pen on paper and you'll see the same.

Comment: you can make your slices shorter, but then you would find a white area in your pie

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0):

This effect is called the Moiré pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

To avoid it make the distance between slices bigger. The amount depends on the size of the pie and the display resolution. To make the distance bigger you could draw  a bigger pie but you'll find that the slices will be fighting over the pixels. You could just live with this effect or you could push the slices outward.